# Contador basico en bucle no cuenta. Porque no lo hace?

Tags: javascript

```
function masMenos(array){
  var positivos=0;
  var negativos=0;
  var ceros=0;
  var fracciones=[positivos,ceros,negativos];

  for (var i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
    if (array[i]<0){
      negativos = negativos +1;
      } else if (array[i]==0){
        ceros=ceros+1;
      } else {
        positivos = positivos +1;
      }
  }

 return fracciones;
  }
```

Comment: Te falta un `=` en el `else if`

Comment: Gracias, ya lo edite y tampoco funciona. Siempre me devuelve un array de solo "ceros"

Comment: También pasa que al momento de asignar los valores al array, dichos valores se pasan en copia y no por referencia, por lo que cuando modifiques tu variable, no se cambiará en el array, ya que lo que el array contiene es una copia de las variables en el momento que se asignaron. intenta retornar así: `return [positivos, ceros, negativos]` en vez de `return fracciones;`

Comment: Ahora si funciono, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que actualizar los datos del arreglo, debido a que cuando creas el arreglo se inicializa con los datos correspondientes que las variables tienen en ese momento.

```
function masMenos(array){
  var positivos=0;
  var negativos=0;
  var ceros=0;
  var fracciones=[];

  for (var i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
    if (array[i]<0){
      negativos = negativos +1;
      } else if (array[i]==0){
        ceros=ceros+1;
      } else {
        positivos = positivos +1;
      }
  }

  fracciones=[positivos,ceros,negativos];

 return fracciones;
  }
```

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo, gracias!